# counting and grouping mysql data

Tags: php, mysql, php-5.3

say I have a table with data like this - a hypothetical racing game

at the end of each game, a user's name, their position in the game and the winnings they earned are added to the table

```
 *****************************************
 | name  | place | date       | winnings |
 | bob   | 1     | 2015-07-08 | 100      |
 | bob   | 2     | 2015-07-07 | 75       |
 | john  | 1     | 2015-07-07 | 100      |
 | john  | 1     | 2015-07-04 | 100      |
 | sarah | 9     | 2015-07-05 | 1000     |
 *****************************************
```

I would use the following query to get this

```
 select h.name, z.place, z.date, z.winnings from races as z, users as h where h.id  = z.user_id order by date desc
```

my question is

how would I get it to output something like this? (add the winnings together and sort with them)

```
 **************************
 | name  | total_winnings |
 | sarah | 1000           |
 | john  | 200            |
 | bob   | 175            |
 **************************
```

as well as how sorted by how many times they won (were in first place)

```
 ***************************
 | name  | won_first_place |
 | john  | 2               |
 | bob   | 1               |
 | sarah | 0               | 
 ***************************
```

Thanks

Comment: What would be the meaning of the date column in the two queries you are trying to produce?

Comment: cleaned it up. sorry for the confusion. the date column's not important for the first two

Comment: Can you give one desired output, instead of two, and have the description match the result to avoid confusion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle both of those queries similarly, because both will require grouping by user.

```
SELECT 
    users.name, 
    SUM(races.winnings) AS total_winnings
FROM users INNER JOIN races ON users.id  = races.user_id
GROUP BY users.id
ORDER BY SUM(races.winnings) DESC
```

should get you the total winnings, and

```
SELECT 
    users.name, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN races.place=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS won_first_place
FROM users INNER JOIN races ON users.id  = races.user_id
GROUP BY users.id
ORDER BY SUM(CASE WHEN races.place=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DESC
```

should get you the number of times the user got first place.

When you use `GROUP BY` you can use many different aggregate functions such as `SUM` on columns in the grouped rows. You can check out the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html) for other options.

Comment: It looks like it does not take into account the total amount of first places

Comment: @vonUbisch I thought, based on the first table representation in the question, that the `place` column appears to represent the number of times the user got first place, rather than which place they got.

Comment: I definitely understand the confusion, OP should have given one desired output. `as well as how sorted by how many times they won (were first place)`

Comment: @vonUbisch The third example in the question does appear to be a sum of the place column, as far as I can tell.

Comment: You're right, but that contradicts with the description of the desired output. OP should clarify.

Comment: ahh, it's their place in the game, not how many times they were first place

Comment: @totalnoob I see. In that case, bob should have a 1 rather than a 3, correct?

Comment: yea, I've updated the question and the data to make it simpler

Comment: @totalnoob Updated the answer as well to reflect my updated understanding of the question. :)

Comment: hey, what if I wanted a count of how many times that user was first place within the same query?

Comment: You could put both of the sums in the same query. It should work fine since the group by is the same. You'd just have to pick which one you wanted to order by.

Comment: do you have a fiddle? if I add a  count(CASE WHEN race_results.place=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS something it counts every row instead of individual - it'll add up anytime john, bob, sarah had place = 1, rather than how many times john had place = 1